# How do I read this JSON string?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json

I am getting this JSON string from an ASP.Net webservice:

```
{"d":{"Table":[{"col1":123,"col2":"name","col3":"name","col4":100,"col5":"\/Date(1153033200000)\/"},{"col1":123,"col2":"name","col3":"name","col4":101,"col5":"\/Date(1153033200000)\/"},{"col1":123,"col2":"name","col3":"name","col4":102,"col5":"\/Date(1153033200000)\/"}]}}
```

In my jQuery how do I reference the Table code so I can loop through the data?

msg.d[i].col1

What am I missing?  msg.d.table[i]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `d` is an object that contains the property `Table`, which is an array of objects that contain the property `col1`.

So, you use `msg.d.Table` to access the array, `msg.d.Table[i]` to access an item in the array, and `msg.d.Table[i].col1` to access the property in the item.

Note that Javascript is case sensetive, so while `msg.d.Table` works, `msg.d.table` won't.

This gets the array and loops through it:

```
var tableArray = msg.d.Table;
$.each(tableArray, function(){
  alert(this.col1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`msg.d` is an object. `msg.d.Table` will give you what you want.

To iterate:

```
$.each(msg.d.Table, function(row) {
  // Get specific value:
  window.alert(row.col1);
  // Iterate through all columns:
  $.each(row, function(column, value) {
    // Do something..
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(msg.d.Table, function(i, val) {
   alert(val.col1);
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's JSON parser:

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_DATA);
```

And then refer to objects directly via the data variable:

```
data.my_property
```